# How to set Opacity for View in android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have created a custom table which could scroll its contents. Am drawing the contents in the OnDraw method. I have made a **header part which is static** and the **body part which scrolls the content**. The problem am facing is **when I scroll vertically**, the row which goes out of view is overlapping with the header row and is shown behind it. It looks ugly as I scroll. I **could not make my header part(nothing but a custom view) as non transparent**. I tried to set Alpha for the view in the construtor.

```
this.setAlpha(255);
//Also tried setting this.setAlpha(0.5)
```

But despite alpha being set to any value the issue still occurs. I also tried to set alpha for the background.

```
view.getBackground().setAlpha(values between 0 to 1).
```

But it throws error for me as my Background is null. I have attached below a screenshot for better understanding.!![image]

Any idea of how to make my header part opaque?

Answer (score 2):

alpha is from 0 to 1.0 
view.setAlpha(0.5f);

Comment: I understand alpha must be between 0 and 1. But Alpha being one, when I cheque view.IsOpaque, it returns false. All I need is when I scroll, the row which is in view alone should be shown, the row that is going out of view should not overlap with the header. Is there any way to achieve this?